# Install Service Pack 3 on SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, service-pack

I have installed SQL Sever 2005 on Windows XP **Service Pack 2** .
When I want to insall Service Pack 3 on SQL Server 2005 I get the blue screen error and I must restart the computer.

How can I solve this problem?
thanks

Comment: Maybe try to install service pack 4.

Answer (score 2):

[Known issue reported on Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/415072/system-crashes-blue-screen-c000021a-unknown-hard-error-when-install-the-sql-server-2005-express-sp3-for-the-first-time)

Which links to

- [Installing SQL Server 2005 SP3 or SQL Server 2008 on builds prior to XP SP3 Can lead to Bug Check (0xF4, Blue screen, Critical Process Termination)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/01/07/installing-sql-server-2005-sp3-or-sql-server-2008-on-builds-prior-to-xp-sp3-can-lead-to-bug-check-0xf4-blue-screen-critical-process-termination.aspx)
- [SQL Server 2005 SP3, SQL Server 2005 SP2 CUs, or SQL Server 2008 may cause XP SP2 to restart](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/petersad/archive/2009/01/20/sql-server-2005-sp3-sql-server-2005-sp2-cus-or-sql-server-2008-may-cause-xp-sp2-to-restart.aspx)

My first question would be why are you still using XP SP2? Instead of Sp3?

Comment: Most corporate laptop users I see on the train are using XP.

Comment: @Jeff O: fair enough. My corporate desktop and laptop are XP. But SP3 came out in April 2008...